# how to change path in OSX maverick?

Tags: macos

trying to set my path, when I do

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

in the terminal I have added a path say /usr/test

after saving this file when I do:

```
echo $ PATH
```

the /usr/test path is not included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add something to your $PATH you do it in .profile or .bash_profile etc 
[example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)